# Bridging two NICs with differents speeds DDOSes subnet when both cables plugged in

Tags: bonding

I have recently configured a new server and wanted to setup the two NICs in it to run in bond-mode 1 and then bridge them. We have this exact setup running on our other servers.

The difference between the old, working, servers and the new one is: The new server has two NICs with different speeds (1 Gb & 5 Gb) while the old servers all have two identical NICs with 1 Gb each.

After setting up the `/etc/network/interfaces` config exactly like on the other servers:

```
auto enp114s0f0
iface enp114s0f0 inet manual

auto enp114s0f1
iface enp114s0f1 inet manual

auto bond-int
iface bond-int inet manual
        slaves enp114s0f0 enp114s0f1
        bond-mode 1

auto bridge-out
iface bridge-out inet static
        bridge_ports bond-int
        bridge_fd 0
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_maxwait 0
        address 10.1.1.101
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 10.1.11.1
```

I first noticed that `ip a` doesn't show `bond-int` being created. I don't know why... it works perfectly fine on all other servers.

So I changed the config to bridge enp114s0f0 and enp114s0f1 directly:

```
auto bridge-out
iface bridge-out inet static
        bridge_ports enp114s0f0 enp114s0f1
        bridge_fd 0
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_maxwait 0
        address 10.1.1.101
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 10.1.11.1
```

This resulted in `ip a` now showing the bridge as up.

However, when I plug in cables into both NICs, the entire subnet DDOSes itself. No other machines can ping each other. As soon as I unplug the cable from the 5 Gb NIC, everything goes back to normal.

When I run `bmon` on the new server and plug in the 5 Gb cable again, it goes from showing 10-20 packets trickeling in per seconds to several K packets coming in at once. As soon as I unplug, it goes back to a few dozen.

Wth is happening here? Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

Wow, next time I should:

`apt-get install ifenslave`

before....

Comment: Amazingly, I now have the problem that unplugging the 1 Gb NIC makes the server lose connectivity, which also cannot be restored by plugging the cable back in. With the 5 Gb NIC unplugging/replugging works as expected, but if I unplug the 1 Gb NIC the network is gone on the server and won't come back until I `systemctl restart networking`...

Comment: If I put the 5 Gb NIC (enp114s0f1) first in `/etc/network/interfaces` in the individual iface blocks and in the `slaves` setting of `bond-int`, then most of the functionality works: Unplugging the 5 Gb still loses connectivity instead of switching to the 1 Gb card, but at least replugging the 5 Gb card restores it.... weird... maybe 1 Gb card is defective?

Comment: And the solution for this was to add `bond-miimon 100 /n bond-downdelay 200 /n bond-updelay 200` to `/etc/network/interfaces`. Everything works now

Comment: Look at the calendar. 2023. Then look into your system. Your system already has all is needed to enslave a NIC: `ip` from `iproute2`. Something like `ip link set eth0 master bond0` does this. And it's a long time (23 years) when you  have to forget about obsolete ifconfig, route, brctl, vconfig, ifenslave, tunctl, netstat etc.; they were *all* replaced with tools from the `iproute2`, mostly `ip` utility. Even Debian had converted its machinery to use iproute2 6 years already, so I believe, since Debian 10 they don't ship these by default.